# When bean names overlap, the log output varies depending on the return type of the configuration method

Tags: java, spring

I learned that if the names of beans registered through component scanning overlap with those registered through configuration methods, overriding occurs.

However, when I mistakenly specified the return type of a method in the configuration as the implementation class instead of the interface during auto-completion, **the log related to overriding was not outputted**. I'm curious about the reason for this.

This is the code for the interface.

```
package hello.core.bean_overriding;

public interface BeanInterface {
}
```

This is the code for the implementation class. Adding the @Component annotation automatically registers it as a bean.

```
package hello.core.bean_overriding;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component  // register bean (name: "beanA")
public class BeanA implements BeanInterface {
    public BeanA() {
        System.out.println("BeanA.BeanA = " + this);
    }
```

**CASE 1: return type of factory method = interface**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = BeanOverridingTest.class)
static class TestConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public BeanInterface beanA() {  // register bean (name: "beanA")
        return new BeanA();
    }
}
```

In this case, the following overriding-related log is printed.
"17:30:59.922 [Test worker] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory --Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanA' with a different definition: ..."

**CASE 2: return type of factory method = implementation class**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = BeanOverridingTest.class)
static class TestConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public BeanA beanA() {  // register bean (name: "beanA")
        return new BeanA();
    }
}
```

In this case, the overriding-related log is not printed.

Thank you for reading through my question, and I'd be even more grateful if you could give me some advice. Wishing you a great day.

Comment: The one with the exact match is ignored as a bean with that name and that type is already registered. Strictly speaking it doesn't override it. In your interface example, at the moment of scanning that method, there is a mismatch in the exact match of the actual class and at that moment an instance isn't available to check the actual type, hence a debug message is printed that it is being overridden.

Comment: @M.Deinum / I understood your explanation as follows: **Case 1)** If a bean with the same name and type already exists at the time of bean registration, the bean that should be registered is treated as registered and not considered as overridden. **Case 2)** Bean registration via the Bean annotated method utilizes the return type of the method as the bean type, so if a bean with the same name but a different type is registered first, it will be overridden. / I'm very grateful for your response. I will study even harder.

Answer (score 1):

If these two cases are in the same context:

The bean 'beanA' was created only once. The second time you try to get bean, the method constructor is no longer executed.

you could rename baen using a different name @Bean("beanAA").